# How to validate which NTP server is currently in use

Tags: android, android-source

I changed the default NTP server in AOSP from time.android.com to something else.

I did it by changing the key `config_ntpServer` in *frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml*

How can I validate on the device whether my change took effect or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the events log by adb logcat -b events:

If the system get time from the ntp server success, you will see:

```
ntp_success: [time.android.com/216.239.35.0,704,860]
```

If failed, you will see:

```
ntp_failure: [time.android.com/216.239.35.0,"failed message"]
```

The related source files are:

core/java/android/util/NtpTrustedTime.java
core/java/android/net/SntpClient.java